# Not able to type quotation mark (") once

Tags: visual-studio-code, text

So in my vs code (or anywhere I type) if I press ' key once it doesn't do anything, but if then I press it again it's giving me two '' so why this is happening ..

is this a bug in windows or it's a setting just like sticky keys? (I haven't turned on sticky keys )

Windows 11 stable
4gb ram 128gb ssd

Comment: I don't think it's a bug with Windows 11 (I'm guessing since I have Windows 10). It might be a problem with your keyboard. If it wireless, make sure you have fresh batteries. And reboot your PC if all fails. I have seen weird behavior like that be solved with a simple reboot.

Comment: it's something with the keyboard layout and IME and has nothing to do with VS Code. You already see that happens anywhere you type

Comment: I was Using the keyboard layout
 "English (United Kingdom) [United States-International]"
which was creating the problem !
thanks for giving me path to get around it !

Comment: same here i was using english international.. changed back to Australia